# Local notifcations using datepicker

Tags: xcode, swift, datepicker

I am using localNotifications for my app.I have a datepicker from which a users picks date and time for the notifications and I also have 3 segmented controls(daily,weekly,monthly).I have done the coding for localnotification and its working.But the segmented control is not working and one more problem if a person chooses two times like one for(1 pm) and second for (2pm) and then the notifications are displaying in both time which i dont want.Below is the code

In appdelegate.swift

```
    let types:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound

    let myAlarmSetting:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: categories as Set<NSObject>)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(myAlarmSetting)
```

In notifications.swift

```
@IBAction func NotificationButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    func cancelLocalNotificationsWithUUID(uuid: String) {
for item in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications {
    let notification = item as! UILocalNotification
    if let notificationUUID = notification.userInfo?["UUID"] as? String {
        if notificationUUID == uuid {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
        }    
    }
    }
    }


    var notifications:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notifications.fireDate = datePicker.date
    notifications.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    notifications.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
    notifications.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
 notifications.userInfo = ["UUID": "YOUR NOTIFICATION ID"]
    switch(frequencysegmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex){
    case 0:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
        break;
    case 1:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear
        break;
    case 2:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear
        break;
    default:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit(0)
        break;
    }
    notifications.alertBody = "quote of the day"
    notifications.category = "First_category"

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notifications)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's happening because you are not canceling the old notification when you schedule a new one, you can always add info to your notification like this:

```
var notification = UILocalNotification()
...
notification.userInfo = ["UUID": "YOUR NOTIFICATION ID"]
```

and whenever you schedule a new notification you should cancel old notifications like this:

```
func cancelLocalNotificationsWithUUID(uuid: String) {
    for item in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications {
        let notification = item as! UILocalNotification
        if let notificationUUID = notification.userInfo?["UUID"] as? String {
            if notificationUUID == uuid {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
func cancelLocalNotificationsWithUUID(uuid: String) {
    for item in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications {
        let notification = item as! UILocalNotification
        if let notificationUUID = notification.userInfo?["UUID"] as? String {
            if notificationUUID == uuid {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func NotificationButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    cancelLocalNotificationsWithUUID("NotificationID")

    var notifications:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notifications.fireDate = datePicker.date
    notifications.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    notifications.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
    notifications.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    switch(frequencysegmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex){
    case 0:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
        break;
    case 1:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear
        break;
    case 2:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear
        break;
    default:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit(0)
        break;
    }

    notifications.userInfo = ["UUID": "NotificationID"]

    notifications.alertBody = "quote of the day"
    notifications.category = "First_category"

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notifications)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

Comment: thanks man it worked and can you also see in my code in the line notifications.repeatinterval = NSCalendarunit.Calendarunitday can you correct that thing

Comment: should i include func cancellocalnotification... in IBAction @Firas

Comment: @shivam Actually I didn't understand the goal behind your code, you should call it whenever you want to cancel the previous notification, so if you have only one notification and it should repeat on a fixed basis then you should call it in your action, please accept the answer if it worked.

Comment: @shivam please accept the answer if it did work, or at least upvote.

Comment: hey i am new to notifications so i can't understand where to post this code.I have to post this code in my IBAction ? @Firas

Comment: You should add the notification.userInfo... In the IBAction before sharedApplication().schedule... And call the cancelLocalNotificationWithUUID function also inside the IBAction but make it in the first line

Comment: @shivam check the updated answer and accept if it worked.

Comment: one more thing do you know how to set it like right now it is set for daily but i also want weekly and monthly for which i have placed segments.Any advice ? @Firas

Comment: You should add a new question and put more details in it.

Comment: @Firas your code is correct and its working but the notifications comes after 30 seconds for example if i set the time to 5pm then the notification will come at 5(30seconds) before 5:1

Comment: @Motivationgym5 I think you should determine the exact minute in the NSDate object, this is a different question please ask a new one maybe someone can help you more.